# Descargar un documento en formato PDF desde una ruta especifica

Tags: html, mvc

compañeros(as) un gusto saludarlos requiero realizar lo siguiente :

tengo un boton que se llama Descargar como se muestra  a continuacion :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que al dar clic me descargue un archivo en formato PDF este archivo estara almacenado en una ruta especifica por ejemplo puede estar en C: para que cuando demos clic en el boton lo puedan descargar sin problema. . . 
Otro punto a reafirmar es que este pdf no esta ligada con informacion en BD ni nada parecido.
Me podrian ayudar .

Saludos.

Comment: En html se puede hacer algo como esto:al  momento de dar click en el botón este te abrirá el pdf y tu tendrás la opción de descargarlo. Ahora si lo que quieres es descargar el PDF  tras que des en el botón sin que este te abra el PDF,  eso se peude realizarlo con PHP. Tengo entendido que no es posible hacerlo solo con html.

Comment: asi es lo que requiero es poder descargar un archivo que tendre guardado en el servidor investigando un poco me funciona el filepath pero solamente con una ruta virtual se descarga al recargar la pagina lo que yo requiero es al momento de darle click con el boton lo descargue. . .